# Stored procedure error in ASP.NET mvc

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, ef-database-first

I am trying to use a stored procedure in my MVC application, However I keep getting this error : The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'GiftworxModel.Card'. A member of the type, 'CardID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name. Any assistance will be appreciated.

My stored procedure

```
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[GetBalance]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@CardNumber nvarchar(20)

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
If Not Exists(Select CardID From Cards With (NOLOCK) Where CardNumber = @CardNumber OR (Cards.CardNumber2 = @CardNumber))
Begin
Select 'Invalid Card Number' as Error
END

Select Sum(TotalAmount) as TotalAmount, StoreCustomerName, StoreCustomerISurname, StoreCustomerEmail, StoreCustomerDOB, StoreCustomerAddress, StoreCustomerCity, 
                         StoreCustomerRegion, StoreCustomerCountry, StoreCustomerCel, StoreCustomerDate, StoreCustomerToken, '' as Error, StoreCustomerID, CardNumber, CardStatus,
                         LoyaltyLevelName, LoyaltyLevel, DiscountLevelAmount, DiscountLevelName, GiftCardEnabled, LoyaltyEnabled, StoreCustomerNumber From (
SELECT        0 AS TotalAmount, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerName, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerISurname, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerEmail, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerDOB, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerAddress, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCity, 
                         StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerRegion, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCountry, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCel, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerDate, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerToken, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerID, 
                         Cards.CardNumber, Cards.CardStatus, LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevelName, LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevel, DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelAmount, DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelName, Cards.GiftCardEnabled, Cards.LoyaltyEnabled, StoreCustomerNumber
FROM            StoreCustomers WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
                         Cards WITH (NOLOCK) ON StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerID = Cards.StoreCustomerID INNER JOIN
                         DiscountLevels WITH (NOLOCK) ON Cards.DiscountLevelID = DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelID AND Cards.CustomerID = DiscountLevels.CustomerID  INNER JOIN 
                         LoyaltyLevels WITH (NOLOCK) ON Cards.LoyaltyLevelID = LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevelID AND Cards.CustomerID = LoyaltyLevels.CustomerID
WHERE         (Cards.CardNumber = @CardNumber) OR (Cards.CardNumber2 = @CardNumber) --WHERE        (Cards.CardID = @CardID)
GROUP BY StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerName, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerISurname, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerEmail, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerDOB, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerAddress, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCity, 
                         StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerRegion, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCountry, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCel, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerDate, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerToken, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerID, 
                         Cards.CardNumber, Cards.CardStatus, LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevelName, LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevel, DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelAmount, DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelName,Cards.GiftCardEnabled, Cards.LoyaltyEnabled, StoreCustomerNumber
Union ALL
SELECT        SUM(Sales.SaleTotalAmount) AS TotalAmount, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerName, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerISurname, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerEmail, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerDOB, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerAddress,
                         StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCity, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerRegion, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCountry, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCel, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerDate, 
                         StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerToken, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerID, Cards.CardNumber, Cards.CardStatus, LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevelName, LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevel, DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelAmount, 
                         DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelName, Cards.GiftCardEnabled, Cards.LoyaltyEnabled, StoreCustomerNumber
FROM            StoreCustomers WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
                         Cards WITH (NOLOCK) ON StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerID = Cards.StoreCustomerID INNER JOIN
                         Sales WITH (NOLOCK) ON Cards.CardID = Sales.CardID INNER JOIN
                         LoyaltyLevels WITH (NOLOCK) ON Cards.LoyaltyLevelID = LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevelID AND Cards.CustomerID = LoyaltyLevels.CustomerID  INNER JOIN
                         DiscountLevels WITH (NOLOCK) ON Cards.DiscountLevelID = DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelID AND Cards.CustomerID = DiscountLevels.CustomerID
WHERE         (Cards.CardNumber = @CardNumber) OR (Cards.CardNumber2 = @CardNumber)--WHERE        (Cards.CardID = @CardID)
GROUP BY StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerName, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerISurname, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerEmail, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerDOB, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerAddress, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCity, 
                         StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerRegion, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCountry, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCel, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerDate, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerToken, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerID, 
                         Cards.CardNumber, Cards.CardStatus, LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevelName, LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevel, DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelAmount, DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelName, Cards.GiftCardEnabled, Cards.LoyaltyEnabled, StoreCustomerNumber

) as x
GROUP BY StoreCustomerName, StoreCustomerISurname, StoreCustomerEmail, StoreCustomerDOB, StoreCustomerAddress, StoreCustomerCity, StoreCustomerRegion, StoreCustomerCountry, StoreCustomerCel, StoreCustomerDate, StoreCustomerToken, StoreCustomerID, 
CardNumber, CardStatus, LoyaltyLevelName, LoyaltyLevel, DiscountLevelAmount, DiscountLevelName, GiftCardEnabled, LoyaltyEnabled, StoreCustomerNumber

END
```

My context class:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<string> GetBalance(string cardNumber)
{
    var cardNumberParameter = cardNumber != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("CardNumber", cardNumber) :
        new ObjectParameter("CardNumber", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<string>("GetBalance", cardNumberParameter);
}
```

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetBalance(string cardNumber)
{

    var balance = db.GetBalance(cardNumber).ToList();

    return View("GetBalance");

}
```

Comment: can you share your view code?

Comment: You do not select CardID in your query, which is exactly what the error tells you. What is your question?

Comment: which select statement does it go in. Sorry man, I'm quite new to stored procedures and accessing them in asp.net

Comment: In your stored procedure mapping you have mapped it to Card class? Then why does the method returns collection of strings. Can you tell us which line of code gives error? Are you able to run the procedure from sql management studio and get the results without any problem?